# How to find month gaps count from monthly data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one dataframe like below:

```
name,date
AAA,201705
AAA,201706
AAA,201707
AAA,201708
AAA,201710
AAA,201711
AAA,201802
AAA,201803
AAA,201804
AAA,201805
AAA,201806
AAA,201807
```

In this dataframe two columns are available i.e. name and date. In the date column only year and month is available in yyyymm format.

In date column values **201709, 201712 and 201801** months are not available.

Need to check all the months are present or not. If any month is not available then need the ouput in below format:

```
name,start_date,end_date,count
AAA,201709,201709,1
AAA,201712,201801,2
```

I am trying to use [pandas diff function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.asfreq.html):

```
#convert column to datetimes
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m')
# get missing values by asfreq
a = df.set_index('date').groupby('name')['name'].apply(lambda x: x.asfreq('MS'))
#filter only NaNs consecutive rows
b = a.notnull().cumsum()[a.isnull()].reset_index(name='g')

#aggregate first, last and count
d = {'date':['first','last'],'name':['first', 'size']}
df = b.groupby('g').agg(d).reset_index(drop=True)
#data cleaning
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
df = df.rename(columns={'date_first':'start_date', 
                        'date_last':'end_date', 
                        'name_first':'name', 
                        'name_size':'count'})
print (df)
  start_date   end_date name  count
0 2017-09-01 2017-09-01  AAA      1
1 2017-12-01 2018-01-01  AAA      2
```

**Detail**:

```
print (a)
name  date      
AAA   2017-05-01    AAA
      2017-06-01    AAA
      2017-07-01    AAA
      2017-08-01    AAA
      2017-09-01    NaN
      2017-10-01    AAA
      2017-11-01    AAA
      2017-12-01    NaN
      2018-01-01    NaN
      2018-02-01    AAA
      2018-03-01    AAA
      2018-04-01    AAA
      2018-05-01    AAA
      2018-06-01    AAA
      2018-07-01    AAA
Name: name, dtype: object
```